# Random spawning in an X and Y axis for several prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

So I created a script that will instantiate a different prefab depending on the key pressed to a specific x,y position. Now I wanted to edit this so that instead of spawning within a specific point, have the prefabs spawn within an x1,x2 , y1,y2 area randomly.

This is the code I'm using as of now

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Instantiator : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Instantiator for Left
    public KeyCode keyToPress;
    public GameObject[] FI;
    public GameObject clone;

    // Update cause update is cooler
    void Update()
    {
        var transform.positionA = Vector2(Random.Range(-12, -10), Random.Range(-1, 1));
        var transform.positionD = Vector2(Random.Range(12, 10), Random.Range(-1, 1));
        var transform.positionS = Vector2(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-6, -5));
        var transform.positionW = Vector2(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(6, 5));

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            clone = Instantiate(FI[0], positionA, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            clone = Instantiate(FI[1], positionD, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            clone = Instantiate(FI[2], positionS, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            clone = Instantiate(FI[3], positionW, Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }
}
```

However, I get a syntax error ["," expected and ";" expected]

Answer (score 0):

Direct Answer:
You need to use the `new` keyword to create a new vector.
You cannot use transform.position as a variable..you have to use `Vector2 positionA = new Vector2(x, y) // or var positionA`

Extra:
You can use `Random.insideUnitCircle` and which gives you a random position inside a circle with radius 1...then you can multiply it with any number if you want to increase the radius...ex `Random.insideUnitCircle * 5` will give you a random position in a circle with a 5 radius.You can also add or subtract it by vectors to shift the circle to different point. If you want a random 3d position...you can use `Random.insideUnitSphere`.
Ex:

```
//Spawn an object between (startpos)Vector2(6f, -5f) to (endpos)Vector2(12f, -10f)
Vector2 middle = new Vector2(startpos.x + endpos.x, startpos.y + endpos.y) / 2; // (6 + 12) / 2 = 18 / 2 = 9(which is the exact middle of 6 and 12)
Instantiate(prefabname, middle + Random.insideUnitCircle * radius, Quaternion.identity);
```

Note: If you want the random position to come from the whole square, you will have to use the traditional `Random.Range` function, also you dont need to create positions every frame...just create it inside the instantiate method.